# QTP - Clicking on a button with a given value

Tags: testing, web, qtp

I've started using QTP last weekend so I'm still a bit confused about some things. 
I've coded a function that opens an URL on IE, performs some actions and writes a report. But I have a little problem: at a certain point the function has to click on a button to go on but this button's value is changed at every refresh of the page.
For example: at the first access the button's value (or label) is "Results List (51)" but, if I refresh the page, the value becomes "Results List (11)". 
What changes is the number inside the brackets (that identifies the number of results inside the list).

Obviously I recorded the action only one time and the result is this: 
Browser("myBrowser").Page("myPage").Frame("myFrame").WebButton("Results List 51)").Click

How can I click on the button without having to worry about it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question reminded me of the days when I was a beginner in QTP ;) I think I still am!
Coming to your question - 
If you don't really care about what is inside the brackets then you can just give Results List*.* but if you want to check if there is a bracket and digits within it then use the value suggested by Motti i.e. Results List (\d+)

Detailed Steps as you are a rookie:
1) Go to Resources->Object Repository
OR
In the Resources pane expand your action and double-Click the local object repository (You recorded hence the objects will be in local)

2) Click on the Concerned Object so that the object properties specific to this object is displayed.

3) Select the property (name?), at the extreme right you will see a button to configure the value, click on it.

4) Type the text Results List (\d+) or Results List*.*, select the checkbox for regular expressions.

5) A message box will appear, Click on No and then OK button.
Your script should run now!

Answer (score 2):

You should open the object repository and have a look at the description that was create for your `WebButton` then make the property in question a regular expression.

In your case the value should be `Results List \(\d+\)`, this means *Result List* followed by open-parentheses, followd by one or more digits (a number) followed by close-parentheses.

Here's an explanation on [how to use regular expressions in UFT](http://www.learnqtp.com/regular-expressions-regularized/).